# I have a bit of code, and no matter how much google-ing I do, i can't solve the compiler error in the .h

Tags: c++

I am trying to generate a quiz program, for school.  My code is as follows

main.cpp:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

#include "getQuestion.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
int mainMenuChoice;
ifstream Bibliography;
//string easyBib;
ifstream easyBib;
ifstream inputFile;

cout << "Quiz Menu\n\n";
cout << "1. Play Game!\n";
cout << "2. Bibliography\n";
cout << "3. Developer Info\n";
//cout << "4. Admin Menu\n";
cout << "4. Exit\n";
cout << "Menu Choice: ";
cin >> mainMenuChoice;

switch (mainMenuChoice) {
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        inputFile.open("Bib.txt");
        inputFile >> easyBib;
        cout << easyBib << endl;
        break;
    case 3:

        break;
    /*case 4:
        break;*/
    case 4:
        cout << "Thank you for playing!" << endl;
        return(0);
    default:
        cout << "Sorry, Invalid Choice!\n";
        return(0);

}
return(0);
}
```

getQuestion.h:

```
#ifndef getQuestion
#define getQuestion

int getQuestion () {

ifstream Question;
ifstream Linker;                //Linker for 2 flies
ifstream Answer;
string A;
string L;               //Linker for 2 flies
string Q;
int line;


Question.open("Question.txt");
Question >> Q;
Answer.open("Answer.txt");
Answer >> A;
Linker.open("Linker.txt");
Linker >> L;


getline(Question,line);
number_of_lines++;
#endif
```

Compiler Errors:

```
Build Social Studies of project Social Studies with configuration Debug

CompileC "build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/Objects-normal/x86/main.o" main.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
cd "/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mfix-and-continue -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -gdwarf-2 -iquote "/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/Social Studies-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/Social Studies-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/Social Studies-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/Social Studies-project-headers.hmap" "-F/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Debug" "-I/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Debug/include" "-I/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/DerivedSources/x86_64" "-I/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/DerivedSources" -c "/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/main.cpp" -o "/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/build/Social Studies.build/Debug/Social Studies.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o"

In file included from /Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/main.cpp:8:
/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/getQuestion.h:4: error: expected unqualified-id before 'int'
/Users/student/Desktop/Social Studies/getQuestion.h:4: error: expected `)' before 'int'
```

Thanks.  Also please don't be mean, I'm new to programming!
I am using Mac OS X v. 10.6.8 and XCode 3.2.6
And before anyone asks me to upgrade anything, I am not the admin (this is a school laptop)

EDIT:
Thanks for the help everyone!  Are there any other problems in the code (relating to performence?)

Comment: You're not supposed to use the same name as a function for an include guard. Generally, defines are at least ALL_CAPS. Also, `getline(Question,line);` won't compile.

Comment: `int getQuestion () {` hanging brace among other problems.

Comment: and you are missing the closing } for the function

Comment: Thanks all!  I fixed those two errors, and added the '#include' directives, but as I said below I got another compiler error in the .cpp.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
#define getQuestion

int getQuestion () {
```

What is happening here is you `#define` the string "getQuestion" to blank, and then you use `int getQuestion()` which gets converted to `int ()` which now doesnt make sense.. good catch by @chris. This is the cause of the errors you are getting, once you fix this I expect the other issues pointed out will appear.

Good rule of thumb when making macros, is to make it such that there is very little to no chance of it matching another name, in this case a function. They are typically All caps both to aid in this, and to make it look obvious you are dealing with a macro. So in this case the include guard could be named `GETQUESTION_H` for example.

Comment: If i add the '_H' it gives errors on most lines in the .h (18 total)

Comment: @Noah1111 Is it like this? If so there should be no problem
`#ifndef GETQUESTION_H
#define GETQUESTION_H`

Comment: I got the .h fixed (Thanks, by the way!) but now i get          'error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>' for the .cpp file (line 33).  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: @Noah1111 Why did you do `//string easyBib;
ifstream easyBib;` Is the error on the line `inputFile >> easyBib;`

Comment: I did that because I was experimenting with assigning an fstream variable to a string literal, that is why it is commented.  That is exactly where the error is.  Why is that, how do I solve it?

Comment: @Noah1111 I dont think there is a over load of >> which handles ifstream input to ifstream. you might want to revert to `string easyBib;`

Comment: it will execute now, but when I select that option in the menu it says "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360" (Minus the quotes).  Any Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @Noah1111 I have no idea about that sorry.. perhaps it merits a different question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem for your compiler error is the #define has the same name as the function.  If you change the preprocessor statements to

```
#ifndef getQuestion_h
#define getQuestion_h
```

your compiler error will be solved.

There are a number of other errors that will cause other compiler errors, but because this is homework, you should try to work those out first.

As a matter of style, you should only have function declarations in a .h file.  You should define the getQuestion function body in another file, such as getQuestion.cpp.

Comment: @chris Thanks! I fixed the identifier to have a better style

Comment: Well, it would typically be in all caps, but at least that's a convention, not part of the standard.

Comment: There are people including me who support the idea of such conventions to become a standard. If that would be not a school project code but something more professional.. then setting up proper processes and regulation is the only way to avoid chaos. Learning and following code style does prevent code errors , e.g. http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml

Comment: Thanks, I solved that compiler error, but got this (line 33 in main.cpp)  'error: ambiguous overload for 'operator>>'  And just btw the code itself isn't my project, but rather the content of the program.